# how to calculate voltage divider

Tags: voltage-divider

[image]

Is VDR applicable for R3 and R4? Why?

I want to calculate the voltage divider across resistor R3

I do like this Vs*R3/R3+R4

Is it true?

Comment: Applicable how?

Comment: this question faced me

Comment: What have you been able to figure out yourself so far?

Comment: What is "VDR"? What is the original question? At what point do you want to calculate the voltage. Your question is very poor.

Comment: I want to calculate the voltage divider across resistor

Comment: I do like this Vs*R3/R3+R4

Comment: What do you mean by Vs? There is no Vs in the schematic.

Comment: What is Vs? I think the answer is "yes" the voltage divider rule is applicable...

Comment: I mean by Vs = V1

Comment: “I do like this Vs*R3/R3+R4” - well R3/R3 is 1... so you end up with Vs+R4? You might want to crack open your text book.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it's applicable. But first you have to determine the voltage on that node between R2, R4, and R6. I will call it V2.

So to do that you calculate the total resistance of (R3 + R4)||R2. I will call this RT. You apply the voltage divider rule to RT and R6 to get V2. The voltage across R3 and R4 is V1 - V2. You can use the voltage divider rule again to get what you want.